# Dependent Drop down lists inside a Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

***tbl_Allocation***

[image]

***tbl_Pool***

[image]

Hey all, I'm trying to setup some Dependent Drop Down lists inside a Table. I've done a lot of "Googling" and tried multiple methods, this is the closest I have managed to get ... hopefully I can paint an accurate picture for you.

I have 2 tables `tbl_Pool` and `tbl_Allocation`. I'd like `Technical Role` to be based on the selection in `Technical Team` and of course `Resource` to be based on both previous cells.

I've come up with the following Formulas:-

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(OFFSET(tbl_Pool[[#Headers],[Technical Role]],MATCH(OFFSET(tbl_Allocation[[#Headers],[Technical Role]],1,-1),tbl_Pool[Technical Team],0),0,COUNTIF(tbl_Pool[Technical Team],OFFSET(tbl_Allocation[[#Headers],[Technical Role]],1,-1)))),"Select Technical Team")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(tbl_Pool[[#Headers],[Resource]],MATCH(OFFSET(tbl_Allocation[[#Headers],[Resource]],1,-1),tbl_Pool[Technical Role],0),0,COUNTIF(tbl_Pool[Technical Role],OFFSET(tbl_Allocation[[#Headers],[Resource]],1,-1))),"Select Technical Role")
```

which I have tested (F9 in the Formula Bar) and am getting the desired results. However, when I create a 'Named Range' using these formulas and then using that 'Name' for the 'Data Validation' it simply does not work.
I've also tried to use the Formulas as the 'Data Validation' and am getting the "Problem with this Formula" error.

So yeah, I'm stuck.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These formulas are totally unsuitable for use in Data Validation, starting with the IFERROR() function but not ending there. I suggest you go back to basics:- Every validation dropdown needs to refer to a list. Create these lists on a dedicated sheet. Give them names. Then make the names dynamic. Finally, teach your dropdowns to select among the lists you created. The idea to have a single list and fill this list with different lines of text simply won't work.

Comment: Thank you Variatus, I've tried to create these on a separate Sheet and then referring to those lists as the 'named range' only I found that as the Allocation table grows the Data Validation would break.

Also, these Formulas I came up with example from the web and have seen them in use on example files ... only not in Tables

Comment: Have you checked [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxReJslyJm8)?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, yes. well part of it anyway. unfortunately my data is not setup exactly the same but the formula in that video is what helped me come up with mine

Comment: So, I've found a new method, which I can get to work ... in theory

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/09/02/create-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-excel/

However, when I add a new Row/Line to tbl_Allocation it breaks.

Any suggestions?